# Can you find and use artefacts in Dwarf Fortress' Adventure Mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have started playing adventure mode for the first time, after dozens of fortress mode plays.

I was wondering if I will find or I could track down some artefacts equipment pieces like a sweet sword, or perhaps a shield.

I would imagine myself as a character from Sword Art Online :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find artifacts that were created in a previous fortress. Putting artifacts in bins made of heavy metals such as lead, gold and platinum will prevent the items from scattering, which happens when a fortress crumbles or is abandoned. There are no other sources of artifact equipment other than past fortresses.

It's unrealistic to equip even a single adventurer with all-artifact gear, but masterwork gear is almost as good and is significantly easier and faster to create. Similarly, store it in heavy bins if you want to be able to find it with an adventurer.

To store items in particular bins, create a stockpile that will only accept artifact quality items, forbid all bins but the ones made of suitable metals (make sure there are some empty bins of those types), and designate the stockpile to take from the stockpiles where your artifacts are stored.

Comment: can you craft or find masterwork items just in adventure mode?

Comment: @Discipol like I said, no.

Comment: But are there upgrades for a weapon aside from the material it is @ made? By upgrade I mean combat stats.

Comment: @Discipol masterwork and artifact equipment have bonuses, other than that no.

Comment: Technically, you can find several masterwork items in a pristine world, but usually they will be either pieces of clothing or weapons, and usually worn/wielded by powerful figures, such as dungeon bosses. The only artifacts made during world creation are books and slabs (due to them containing secrets). You can also craft items in Adventurer (albeit in a very weird way) using DFHack.

Comment: Using the DFHACK 'Lair' command will also prevent item scatter on fortress abandon; it marks your fortress as a monster lair. The 'Lair reset' command reverses this effect.